# Formula on one sheet using indirect reference to contents of a cell on another sheet returning #VALUE

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Excel 2010. Formula on Sheet1: `=COUNTIF($D$9:INDIRECT($D$7),"qa")` returns the count of cells that contain the text `qa` in range `$D$9` through whichever cell is referenced in cell `&D$7`.

However, moving the formula to another sheet and adjusting to reference the original sheet returns #VALUE error. New formula is `=COUNTIF('Sheet2'!$D$9:INDIRECT('Sheet2'!$D$7),"qa")`.  Can anyone help?

Comment: =countif('Sheet2!$D$9':INDIRECT('Sheet2!$D$7'),"qa") should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'sheet2'!$D$9:"&'Sheet2'!$D$7),"qa")`

Answer (score 0):

If `Sheet2!D7` contains, for example, `D42`, the evaluation of your formula will progress like this:

```
    =COUNTIF('Sheet2'!$D$9:INDIRECT('Sheet2'!$D$7),"qa")

→   =COUNTIF('Sheet2'!$D$9:INDIRECT("D42"),"qa")

→   =COUNTIF('Sheet2'!$D$9:$D$42,"qa")
```

But this is misleading – it’s not equivalent to typing `'Sheet2'!$D$9:$D$42`;
rather, since the `$D$42` is generated independently,
it is interpreted as referring to cell `D42` ***on the current sheet***
– and that, of course, results in an invalid range. 
To address the range `'Sheet2'!$D$9:$D$42`, change your formula to

```
    =COUNTIF(Sheet2!$D$9:INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&Sheet2!$D$7),"qa")
```

which will evaluate as

```
→   =COUNTIF(Sheet2!$D$9:INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&"D42"),"qa")

→   =COUNTIF(Sheet2!$D$9:INDIRECT("Sheet2!D42"),"qa")

→   =COUNTIF(Sheet2!$D$9:Sheet2!$D$42,"qa")

→   =COUNTIF(Sheet2!$D$9:$D$42,"qa")
```

Or use Barry’s more economical version.

P.S. It seems that you don’t need the quotes in `'Sheet2'`
unless your sheet name contains spaces or other special characters.